# Problem about the throwing of three dice

Tags: probability

I have this problem:

> If three dice are thrown, what is the probability that the sum of the
>   numbers obtained is 6?

The only solution that occurs to me is to look for all the possible cases by making the sample space, however, I can not even make the sample space quickly. For example, for the release of two dice, you can quickly make the sample space with this table:

[image]

However, for the release of 3 dice I do not know how to do it, and doing it one by one will be a lot of time !, then my questions are:

1) Is there a "trick" to get the sample space, quickly, like that table, but for the release of 3 dice or even more?

2) Is there a more optimal solution than to count all the cases for this exercise?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, each die contributes at least one, so you only need three more.  The triples of non-negative integers that sum to $3$ are $(1,1,1)$,  the three permutations of $(3,0,0)$, and the six permutations of $(2,1,0)$..  Can you finish from here?

Comment: The sum must be $6$ not $3$ @lulu

Comment: Read what I wrote.  Each die contributes at least one, so my triples just describe the excess.  Thus, for example, the triple $(3,0,0)$ corresponds to the dice throws $(4,1,1)$.  Just add one to each slot.

Comment: To stress: the dice throws that sum to $6$ are $(2,2,2)$, the three permutations of $(4,1,1)$ and the six permutations of $(3,2,1)$.

Comment: So, the triples are $(3, 0, 0), (2, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)$ that are 13/216 cases

Comment: I count them as $1+3+6=10$.  Not sure where you got $13$.

Comment: My bad, I forgot divide $(3, 0, 0)$ by $2!$, that is $3$

Comment: Right.  There are only three permutations of $(3,0,0)$ (or $(4,1,1)$ if we want to use the actual dice throws).

Comment: Ok, but the answers are$ A)4/216 b)5/216 c) 6/216 d)7/216 e)8/216$

Comment: Well, I don't see anything wrong with my calculation.  I mean...I've explicitly listed $10$ possible dice throws that sum to $6$.  I suppose you could argue that I might have missed some, but that would make the answer even higher.

Comment: Thanks anyway !

Comment: Just as a sanity check, [here's](https://www.thoughtco.com/probabilities-for-rolling-three-dice-3126558) a reference which also gets $10$.

Comment: FWIW, this is equal to the coefficient of $z^3$ in $\frac1{6^3}(z+z^2+z^3+z^4+z^5+z^6)^3$, which works out to be $\frac1{6^3}(5C2)=10/216$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the table of sample space for $n=2$ dice.

For $n=3$ dice, add the third die number to the table entries:
$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
d_1/d_2&1&2&3&4&5&6\\
\hline
1&2&3&4&5&\color{red}6&7\\
2&3&4&5&\color{red}6&7&8\\
3&4&5&\color{red}6&7&8&9\\
4&5&\color{red}6&7&8&9&10\\
5&\color{red}6&7&8&9&10&11\\
6&7&8&9&10&11&12\\
\end{array} \Rightarrow \\
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
d_1/d_2(d_3=1)&1&2&3&4&5&6\\
\hline
1&3&4&5&\color{red}6&7&8\\
2&4&5&\color{red}6&7&8&9\\
3&5&\color{red}6&7&8&9&10\\
4&\color{red}6&7&8&9&10&11\\
5&7&8&9&10&11&12\\
6&8&9&10&11&12&13\\
\end{array} \text{or} \begin{array}{c|ccccc}
d_1/d_2(d_3=2)&1&2&3&4&5&6\\
\hline
1&4&5&\color{red}6&7&8&9\\
2&5&\color{red}6&7&8&9&10\\
3&\color{red}6&7&8&9&10&11\\
4&7&8&9&10&11&12\\
5&8&9&10&11&12&13\\
6&9&10&11&12&13&14\\
\end{array} \text{or} \\
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
d_1/d_2(d_3=3)&1&2&3&4&5&6\\
\hline
1&5&\color{red}6&7&8&9&10\\
2&\color{red}6&7&8&9&10&11\\
3&7&8&9&10&11&12\\
4&8&9&10&11&12&13\\
5&9&10&11&12&13&14\\
6&10&11&12&13&14&15\\
\end{array} \text{or} \begin{array}{c|ccccc}
d_1/d_2(d_3=4)&1&2&3&4&5&6\\
\hline
1&\color{red}6&7&8&9&10&11\\
2&7&8&9&10&11&12\\
3&8&9&10&11&12&13\\
4&9&10&11&12&13&14\\
5&10&11&12&13&14&15\\
6&11&12&13&14&15&16\\
\end{array}$$ 
So, the required probability is:
$$\frac{1+2+3+4}{6^3}=\frac{10}{216}$$
Inference: Once you have the table for $n=2$ dice, for $n=3$, you can imagine the results of adding the third die number and seeing which entries are effected.

Question: Can you find the probability of getting the sum of $8$ when $3$ dice are rolled? Hint: Try not to create the tables for $n=3$ dice, but infer (generalize) from the table for $n=2$.

Answer:

> $\frac{1+2+3+4+5+6}{6^3}=\frac{21}{216}.$

Comment: Generalizing from the table of $n = 2$, without make the table, my thought was: The probability of get a sum of $8$ in a throwing of two dice is $5/36$, but when is a throwing of three dice and the third dice is $1$ the probabilty of $8$ is now the probability of $7$ in the throwing of two dices, now with the third dice is $2$ the probabilty of $8$ is now the probabilty of $6$ in the throwing of two dices, and so with others

Comment: However the answer $26/256$ is incorrect, must be $21/256$ that is $6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 +1/ 216$

Comment: I see you got it very well. Yes, it must be $21/216$.

Answer (score 3):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

Let $(d_1,d_2,d_3)$ be the result of the dice throws and let $x_i=d_i-1$.  Then $$\sum d_i=6\iff \sum x_i=3$$

and of course $0≤x_i≤5$.

The triples of non-negative numbers that sum to $3$ can be enumerated as $(1,1,1)$, $(3,0,0)$ and its permutations, $(2,1,0)$ and its permutations.  There are three permutations of $(3,0,0)$ and six of $(2,1,0)$ so we get $10$ possible triples for the $x_i$.  Thus there are $10$ possible triples for the $d_i$.

Since each triple is equally probable and there are $216$ triples the answer is $\boxed {\frac {10}{216}}$

Note:  the numbers here are very small so it is easy to do the count by explicit enumeration.  If, say, we had a large number of dice this would become inconvenient.  In those cases,  [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) gives the answer, at least when the desired sum is not greater than the maximal value a single die could show.

Comment: Have you an example of exercise with more of three dices and solving with Stars and Bars?

Comment: @Mattiu  Well, there aren't many examples with ordinary dice since you need the target sum to be less than or equal to the highest face on a die.  Of course, you can generate good examples using dice with more faces.  "If you throw a fair $20-$sided die $10$ times, what is the probability that the sum of the values is $19$?"  That sort of thing.

Comment: @Mattiu  To be clear:  the bound isn't exactly the highest value on a die, since you can't throw a $0$.  You can answer "what's the probability that three tosses of a fair die sums to $8$?" using Stars and Bars, since none of the triples that sum to $8$ can have a $7$ or higher.  But you can't handle a target sum of, say, $12$ so easily because Stars and Bars will allow triples like $(8,2,2)$ which aren't actually possible.